# Synching Facebook group events -> Google Calendar -> public RSS or similar

Tags: google-calendar, rss, facebook-groups, facebook-events, yahoo-pipes

We have a Facebook group where various people create events. To make them more widely visible (not everyone has a Facebook login), we share them (read-only) via [Wallflux](https://www.wallflux.com/info/58464537548) to a Google calendar too. This is convenient for those with Google logins, but for those without, we further used to create a [public version via Yahoo Pipes / RSS](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?Facebook_ID=58464537548&_id=1301d12f49b904e56afe3f420366a3c4&_render=rss) (again read-only, and no login of any type required).

Yahoo Pipes is now defunct, so we're looking for another free & easy way to do this. We have no server (can't install apps anywhere) or budget, so the ideal would be a web app somewhat like Yahoo Pipes, where we can simply tell people a URL and when they access it, it reads in from either the GCal or FB URLs and outputs a basic listing that *everyone* can view (even just the event's basic date/time/title). Most of the 'Yahoo Pipe replacements' we've seen (along with IFTTT, Zapier etc.) look too complex: we only need one function. Suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need something beyond Google Calendar? You can make Google calendars public. Does your final product need to be RSS?

Comment: The Google Calendar is public, but when tested with someone without any Google login, they were unable to view it - it asked them to log in or create a Google account. It doesn't have to be RSS - that just seemed the only option at the time of getting it 100% public.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that you need anything beyond Google Calendar.

To test, I created a calendar and added some events. Then I made it public.

Then I went to Calendar settings and chose the URL for the iCal version of the calendar. The URL looks like this: `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/{alphanumeric key}%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics`

I then opened another browser and made sure I didn't have any Google accounts logged in. I went to Outlook.com and imported my calendar link and it was added without a hitch. So I think making your calendar public and publishing the `.ics` URL will do what you want.

If you want something that will do more to your Calendar data, you probably want to ask about it on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Hmm - I see the point, although you're using an Outlook.com login to access the data and I'm hoping for something that produces a format that Joe Public could read without any logins or extra software - plain text would be great and RSS came close to that. I will try SR as you suggest, but further suggestions here would also be good - I'll leave the thread open for now.

Comment: Got nothing at SoftRec http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27855/web-app-to-synch-facebook-group-events-and-or-google-calendar-to-public-rss-or but now have a **convoluted** solution. Making a FB app failed (can't read from groups with an app access token; maybe a dummy FB user account might work?). IFTTT fails to read Wallflux's calendar output. But Facebook > Wallflux > Google Calendar > Zapier > Evernote seems to work. QED: https://www.facebook.com/groups/thanetclassics/events/ --> https://www.evernote.com/pub/enoteb156/thanetclassics - if only there were an easier way!